# How to get http status and detailed response from an API in AWS using the Amplify framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, amplify-ios

In my AWS project, I created webservices using Lambda and API Gateway.
Those webservices are called by my iOS app, using the Amplify framework.

In my lambda functions:

- I return something like the following when there is no error:

```js
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "example_key_1": "example_value",
            "example_key_2": 123456789
        })
    };
```

- I return something like the following when there is an error:

```js
    return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "custom_error_code": 333333
        })
    };
```

And from my iOS app, I call my API by doing something like the following:

```swift
    Amplify.API.post(request: request) { result in
        switch result
        {
            case .success(let data):
                print("success: \(data)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error: \(error)"
        }
    }
```

Now, here are the infos I need to get from the response of the API:

- the status code, when there is an error
- the body of the response, whether there is an error or not

In other words, I need to get in my iOS app the whole content of each `return` of the lambda, when I call the API.

It seems easily doable with the Amplify framework for Javascript, according to [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4144), but I can't find the equivalent for iOS or Android.

How can I achieve that with the Amplify framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Amplify Android](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/android#make-a-post-request)

```kotlin
val body = JSONObject()
    .put("name", "Mow the lawn")
    .toString()
    .toByteArray()
val request = RestOptions.builder()
    .addPath("/todo")
    .addBody(body)
    .build()

Amplify.API.post(request,
    { response ->
        if (!response.code.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w("TAG", "non-200 return code")
        } else {
            val data = repsonse.data.asString()
            Log.i("Demo", "OK! Data = $data")
        }
    },
    { failure ->
        Log.e("Demo", "No response from server", failure)
    }
)
```

#### [Amplify iOS](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/ios#make-a-post-request)

```swift
let request = RESTRequest(path: "/todo", body: "my new Todo".data(using: .utf8))
Amplify.API.post(request: request) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let data):
        let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
        print("Success \(str)")
    case .failure(let apiError):
        switch apiError {
        case .httpStatusError(_, let response):
            println("\(response.statusCode)")
        else:
            println("No response from server")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't get it: for Amplify iOS, how do I get the body of the response, in case of error 400?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours when developing integrating API Gateway in iOS project. Actually I raised a PR for that. [Take a look.](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/pull/657). Unfortunately they closed that PR. But anyway I started using my own [fork](https://github.com/hakanyildizay/amplify-ios/tree/httpError3) for my project. It has been live for 2 months. And I haven't faced any issues.

Hope it would help.

Comment: Hi I just checked it finally they subclassing HTTPURLResponse with AWSHTTPURLResponse (since version 1.7), so now you can use `if case let .httpStatusError(statusCode, response) = error, let awsResponse = response as? AWSHTTPURLResponse {
     if let responseBody = awsResponse.body {
         print("Response contains a \(responseBody.count) byte long response body")
     }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.7 you can use:

```
if case let .httpStatusError(statusCode, response) = error, let awsResponse = response as? AWSHTTPURLResponse {
 if let responseBody = awsResponse.body {
     print("Response contains a \(responseBody.count) byte long response body")
 }
}
```

As stated in PR [#1076](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/pull/1076)